# How to read an audio file from the sdcard folder

Tags: android, audio

This seems like such an easy task, but i can just not get it to work. Ive read other questions' solution to no avail.

I am using the ADT and running my code using an Virtual Device (with a sdcard config of 200mb).

In my project dir i created an folder called sdcard which is now locaded under the res folder. Inside the sdcard folder i created another folder called audio and copied an audio file to that folder. So the structure looks like this, projectFolder/sdcard/audio/sound.mp3  .. Note, i didnt add these folders and file from code! (if that matters).

Now i want to play this sound when i click a button (the button works). I code the following:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

try {
mPlayer.setDataSource(path+"/audio/sound.mp3"); // The ADT tells me that i have to surround 
mPlayer.prepare();                              // these two statements with try catch. why? 
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} //Some more exceptions below.

mPlayer.start();
```

When i run this i get an IOException Error (which was one of my catch exceptions).

So what am i doing wrong? It works when i add the sound to res/raw and use that way to play the sound.

Logcat

```
07-01 16:05:07.430: I/MainActivity(661): MEDIA_MOUNTED True!!!!
07-01 16:05:07.430: I/MainActivity(661): Complete path = /storage/sdcard/audio/sound.mp3
07-01 16:05:07.570: E/MediaPlayer(661): error (1, -2147483648)
07-01 16:05:07.580: W/System.err(661): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
07-01 16:05:07.590: W/System.err(661):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
07-01 16:05:07.600: W/System.err(661):  at com.example.acceptedonphone.MainActivity.startSome(MainActivity.java:47)
07-01 16:05:07.600: W/System.err(661):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-01 16:05:07.600: W/System.err(661):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-01 16:05:07.620: W/System.err(661):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
07-01 16:05:07.620: W/System.err(661):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
07-01 16:05:07.620: W/System.err(661):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
07-01 16:05:07.620: W/System.err(661):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-01 16:05:07.630: W/System.err(661):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-01 16:05:07.630: W/System.err(661):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-01 16:05:07.630: W/System.err(661):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-01 16:05:07.630: W/System.err(661):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-01 16:05:07.630: W/System.err(661):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-01 16:05:07.640: W/System.err(661):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-01 16:05:07.640: W/System.err(661):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-01 16:05:07.640: W/System.err(661):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what's in your logcat?

Comment: See edited. And i just tried it on a Real Device (sony xperia) and worth to note is that the logcat than says "QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present" and the Complete path = /storage/emulated/0/audio/sound.mp3

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` method:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

 MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();    
    try {
    mPlayer.setDataSource(path+"/audio/sound.mp3"); 
    mPlayer.prepare();                              
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }     
    mPlayer.start();
```

or using the path `/mnt/sdcard/audio/sound.mp3`, it worked for me too :

```
String path = "/mnt/sdcard/"
MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();    
try {
mPlayer.setDataSource(path+"/audio/sound.mp3"); 
mPlayer.prepare();                              
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}     
mPlayer.start();
```

*** be sure to have the .mp3 file inside /mnt/sdcard/audio/**

Comment: Neither worked for me :(. And i am using the Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() the getPath() has to be included otherwise it wont retrive a string. The "/mnt/sdcard/" didnt work as well, and the ADT says to use the getExternalStorageDirectory()... When it worked for you, are you running the code on a VM or a real device? And how did you add the music file? Did you create a folder called sdcard under your res folder?

Comment: can you look at the permissions for the directory?  It *should* be accessible to your app but maybe, for some reason, it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot the following permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

The message "QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present" is quite misleading.

Answer (score 0):

This code is worked for me which may help for you...

```
final String MEDIA_PATH = newEnvironment().getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
 File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
 if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) 
{
  for (File file : home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) 
{
   HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
      song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0(file.getName().length() - 4)));
                song.put("songPath", file.getPath());
// Adding each song to SongList
        songsList.add(song);
            }
        }
```

`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.